# Pandas count rows in other df corresponding to conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dfs: df and df0

df looks like this:

```
foo bar baz
A   1   5
A   1   10
A   1   18
A   2   14
A   2   18
A   2   22
A   6   6
A   6   15
```

df0 like this:

```
foo bar baz
A   1   0
A   2   7
A   6   5
```

"foo" can take other values than "A" in both dfs.

I want to add to each row of df the number of rows of df0 for which row.foo == df0.foo and row.bar < df0.bar and row.baz >= df0.baz.

The output would thus be:

```
foo bar baz n
A   1   5   0
A   1   10  2
A   1   18  2
A   2   14  1
A   2   18  1
A   2   22  1
A   6   6   0
A   6   15  0
```

I have a working version (below), but it iterates over the df, which is inherently slow (~30 iterations/second, df can have millions of rows). Is there a vectorised/faster way to accomplish the same?

```
rows = []

for row in df.itertuples():
     rows.append([row.baz, row.foo, row.bar, len(df0.loc[(row.bar < df0.bar) & (row.baz >= df0.baz) & (row.foo == df0.foo)])])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["baz", "foo", "bar", "n"])
```

Comment: How did you get `n=4` for the third row?

Comment: @Erfan oops. I computed the output with df itself instead of df0. Mistakes should have been corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve this by doing a `outer merge`. Than checking your conditions and finally using `GroupBy.sum` to get your `n` column:

```
dfm = df.assign(key=df.index).merge(df0, on='foo', suffixes=['', '_0'])
m = (dfm['bar'] < dfm['bar_0']) & (dfm['baz'] >= dfm['baz_0'])
df['n'] = m.groupby(dfm['key']).sum()

  foo  bar  baz  n
0   A    1    5  1
1   A    1   10  2
2   A    1   18  2
3   A    2   14  1
4   A    2   18  1
5   A    2   22  1
6   A    6    6  0
7   A    6   15  0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much faster. Don't know why I didn't think of it myself, it's not that complex at all.